# Unable to install a theme in Silverstripe

Tags: html, content-management-system, silverstripe

I am trying to install this theme in SilverStripe:
http://www.silverstripe.org/woody-theme/

Here is what I did:

- I copied the code/Page.php & CustomSiteConfig.php in the mysite folder.
- Also copied the last line of _config.php as mentioned in the link.
- Then copied the templates/woody folder to themes directory.
- copied the woodybox into the root folder.
- Modified the mysite/_config.php file to include the line: SSViewer::set_theme('woody');

Still, the site shows server error. I think its an error with installation of the theme. Also I am able to install other themes correctly.

Comment: Add this to your _config.php file and it should give you a more descriptive SilverStripe error: Director::set_environment_type('dev'); Also - did you run a dev/build after installing the theme? e.g. mydomain.com/dev/build?flush=1 (add the flush to clear the template cache).

Comment: Besides doing the two things above: What's the actual error? If it's a server-side error, it's in the log files. If you're having root access it should be in /var/log/apache2/error.log (Debian / Ubuntu) otherwise somewhere in your provider's web administration interface.

Comment: @ShaneGarelja yup I had run dev/build.

Comment: @xeraa There are two errors, I doubt if both were there or one of them:

Comment: PHP Warning:  include_once() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\SilverStripe-v2.4.7/mysite/code/Page_old.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\SilverStripe-v2.4.7/sapphire;C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\SilverStripe-v2.4.7/sapphire/parsers;C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\SilverStripe-v2.4.7/sapphire/thirdparty;.;C:\\xampp\\php\\PEAR') in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\SilverStripe-v2.4.7\\sapphire\\core\\Core.php on line 213, referer: http://localhost/SilverStripe-v2.4.7/Security/login?BackURL=%2FSilverStripe-v2.4.7%2Fadmin

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Page' not found in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\SilverStripe-v2.4.7\\sapphire\\core\\model\\ErrorPage.php on line 14, referer: http://localhost/SilverStripe-v2.4.7/Security/login?BackURL=%2FSilverStripe-v2.4.7%2Fadmin

Comment: also I have changed the theme now.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there is a file *C:/xampp/htdocs/SilverStripe-2.4.7/mysite/code/Page.php* which has ``class Page extends SiteTree {``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its clear from the error logs that you haven't run `/dev/build?flush=1`

Remove everything & try installing once again, I tried & it worked fine for me.